# Troubleshooting creating a file and attempting to copy it with Python

Tags: python, file-copying

## So im trying to create a file using argv and attempting to copy this file afterwards, when i try to run it i get errors at line 16. This is for educational purposes i tried to ge this work, after following "Learning python the hard way" ebook.

```
Error message:
   file "new_prog.py, line 16, in <module>
     newfile.write(line1)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

## Script below

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

newfile, nyfil = argv
print "First we erase is incase it already exists, filename is %r." % newfile

print "We are going to attempt to write a file and copy it."
newfile = raw_input("New filename: ")

print "Write the first line of the document"
line1 = raw_input("First line: ")
print "Write the second line of the document"
line2 = raw_input("Second line: ")
print "Write the last lines, can be coaherent"
lines = raw_input("last lines: ")

newfile.write(line1)
newfile.write("\n")
newfile.write(line2)
newfile.write("\n")
newfile.write(lines)
newfile.write("End of document")
newfile.close()

print "Closing %r for copying" % (newfile)
print "Checking if the new file exists. %r" % exists(nyfil)
raw_input("Press a key to continue")

nyfil = open(newfile, 'w')
nyfil = write(newfile)

nyfil.close()
print "All done, files are printed and copied"
```

## New code that is working, thanks.

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

newfile, nyfil = argv
print "First we erase is incase it already exists, filename is %r." % newfile

print "We are going to attempt to write a file and copy it."
newfile = raw_input("New filename: ")

print "Write the first line of the document"
line1 = raw_input("First line: ")
print "Write the second line of the document"
line2 = raw_input("Second line: ")
print "Write the last lines, can be coaherent"
lines = raw_input("last lines: ")

with open(newfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(line1)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(line2)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(lines)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write ("End of document")

print "Closing %r for copying" % (newfile)
print "Checking if the new file exists. %r" % exists(nyfil)
raw_input("Press a key to continue")

with open(newfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(nyfil)

print "All done, files are printed and copied"
```

Comment: sry about that, edited post

Comment: Why the [tag:makefile] tag ?

Answer (score 0):

`newfile = raw_input("New filename: ")`

newfile is a string not a file object so the error makes sense. You  need to do something like:

```
with open(newfile, "w") as f:
    f.write(line1)
    f.write("\n")
    etc....
```

I am not entirely sure what some of your code is doing but this example will show how to take a file name as command line arg and write the lines you input to it:

```
def write_to_file(newfile):
    print "You entered filename  {}".format(newfile) # string formatting

    print "We are going  to write to a file."
    newfile = raw_input("New filename: ")

    print "Write the first line of the document"
    line1 = raw_input("First line: ")
    print "Write the second line of the document"
    line2 = raw_input("Second line: ")
    print "Write the last lines, can be coaherent"
    lines = raw_input("last lines: ")
    with open(newfile, "w") as f: # use with to open files as it closes them automatically
            f.write(line1)
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(line2)
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(lines)
            f.write("End of document")
    print "Finished writing to {}".format(newfile)
if __name__ =="__main__": 
    write_to_file(sys.argv[1]) # command line arg
```

Save script as `foo.py` then run it with `python foo.py foo.txt` and it will create and write your input to the `foo.txt` file.